How to revoke a (or all) notifications if the app is killed
currently, I'm handling a notification task using react-native + react-native-firebase to push notifications. If the user has read a notification on the website, I want to revoke that notification on their mobile app and reset badge count (like Facebook. Gmail, ...) in case the app is killed.
It seemed impossible with react-native-firebase so I tried coding native modules. I tried the Android app first, but I still have no idea how to resolve it. Please help!

This solution requires sending an FCM data message instead of a notification message from the server.
Starting with the assumption that a user has more than one device FCM token accessible from your server.

On the server, create a unique identifier for every message sent to a user's device. For example, SENT_MESSAGE_ID = "GOOD_MORNING_MESSAGE_ID_FOR_USER_123" should identify a message sent to all the devices a user owns (MOBILE and WEB).
Create the data message on the server and add SENT_MESSAGE_ID to the payload.
Send the data message from the server to the respective devices.
Save the SENT_MESSAGE_ID to the database after sending the data
message.
On the device, show a local notification and grab the Notification_ID, then save the SENT_MESSAGE_ID (from the payload) and NOTIFICATION_ID to the device database/SharedPreference for later. This can be done in both notificationReceivedForeground() and notificationReceivedBackground()
When a user views a notification on a device, check the server to see if the viewed SENT_MESSAGE_ID still exist, if so, send another data message to the user's other devices. Let's call this the cancellation message. The message's payload should contain the SENT_MESSAGE_ID and a flag identifying it as a cancellation FCM message.
Delete the SENT_MESSAGE_ID from your server's database so that another cancellation FCM is not sent again.
Upon receipt of the cancellation FCM data message on the user's other devices, use the SENT_MESSAGE_ID from the payload to retrieve the NOTIFICATION_ID that holds the cancellable notification (that is showing on the user's device) and cancel the notification. This should remove the notification from the device.

You can cancel the notifications with Notifications.cancelLocalNotification("NOTIFICATION_ID"); if you use the react-native-notifications package.
